# Smooth content change

Tags: c#, wpf

I've created simple screen manager in my application that is based on MainWindow's Context change

```
public void SetScreen(UserControl pScreen)
{
    this.Content = pScreen;
}
```

What I want is to add some effect to this transition, make this change smooth, I mean it should work like slider.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: [StoryBoard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.storyboard(v=vs.110).aspx) with an animated transition what you are looking for? You could mess with opacity to fade in and out.

Comment: Do some googling for "WPF Transitions".  Plenty of developers have tackled this feature before, and there's some decent code samples out there.